# Script won't exit

Tags: linux, bash, gtk

I made an extremely simple script that shows a gtkdialog and lets you choose between running one of two other scripts to set your dock. But when you click the button, it doesn't close the script. How do I make it exit after it does it's thing?

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

GTKDIALOG=gtkdialog 
export MAIN_DIALOG=' 

<window title="Dock Selector" icon-name="gtk-about" resizable="true" width-request="310" height-request="310"> 

<vbox> 
<hbox space-fill="true" space-expand="true"> 
    <button>     
        <label>Deluxe (lots of eye candy, higher cpu usage)</label> 
        <action>switch-cairo && exit 1</action> 
    </button> 
</hbox>  
<hbox space-fill="true" space-expand="true"> 
    <button>     
        <label>Light (low cpu usage)</label> 
        <action>switch-ocd && exit 1</action> 
    </button> 
</hbox> 
</vbox> 
</window> 
' 

case $1 in 
-d | --dump) echo "$MAIN_DIALOG" ;; 
*) $GTKDIALOG --program=MAIN_DIALOG --center ;; 

esac
```

And here's one of the scripts it calls:

```
#!/bin/sh
killall -9 ocd-Dock
killall -9 cairo-dock
cairo-dock -o
sed -i 's/cairo-dock -o/ocd-Dock/g' /usr/bin/autostart 
exit
```

edit: Yup, putting & on the end fixed it. Cheers!

Comment: Maybe you need to run `cairo-dock -o` in the background with `&`.

Comment: Are you really sure you need `kill -9` here?  It's usually the sign of an extremely buggy program.  You should usually try the less draconian signals first, and only bring out the big hammer when those do not work.

Comment: @ Barmar: That was it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your other script in the background. Your main script waits for it to exit, but for some reason it doesnt...

You can accomplish that (like already mentioned in the comments) by using the "&" after your command, like this

```
*) $GTKDIALOG --program=MAIN_DIALOG --center & ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dialog box for GTK or the cairo dock, is having the control, run them in background using "&" and the control should come back to your script, which should fix your issue.